# How could i select a specific characters in an array at JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Can anyone help at this exercise:

Create a function named `extractPassword` which takes an array of characters (which includes some trash characters) and returns a string with only valid characters (a - z, A - Z, 0 - 9).

Here's an example **:**

```
extractPassword(['a', '-', '~', '1', 'a', '/']); // should return the string 'a1a'
extractPassword(['~', 'A', '7', '/', 'C']); // should return the string 'A7C'
```

I have done until here **:**

```
var extractPassword = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < extractPassword.length; i++) {
    var output = "";
    switch (extractPassword[i]) {
      case '-':
      case '~':
      case '/':
        break;
      default:
        output = output + extractPassword[i];
    }
    return output;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const extractPassword = (str) => {
  return str.join('').match(/[a-z0-9]/gi)
}

console.log(extractPassword(['a', '-', '~', '1', 'a', '/']).toString().replace(/,/g, ''));
console.log(extractPassword(['~', 'A', '7', '/', 'C']).toString().replace(/,/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression [a-z0-9] means any English letter or number and `g` as a global flag and `i` as a case-insensitive.

```js
const extractPassword = (str) => {
  return str.join('').match(/[a-z0-9]/gi).join()
}

console.log(extractPassword(['a', '-', '~', '1', 'a', '/']));
console.log(extractPassword(['~', 'A', '7', '/', 'C']))
```

Comment: This options are correct, but its not the way they ask. Can be made using "function"?

Comment: It's already with extractPassword function, What do you mean by "function"?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with the help of `RegEx`.

Explanation of Regex `/[a-zA-Z0-9]/ig` **:**

```
[ : beginning of character group
a-z : any lowercase letter
A-Z : any uppercase letter
0-9 : any digit
] : end of character group
i : ignore case sensitivity 
g : check for all occurrence in a provided string
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
function extractPassword(arr) {
    return arr.join().match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/ig);
}

const res = extractPassword(['a', '-', '~', '1', 'a', '/']);

console.log(res.join(''));
```

***Update :*** As author wants to do this with a plain JS without `RegEx`.

```js
const str = [];

function extractPassword(arr) {
  const arrStr = arr.join('');
  for (var i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
    var word = arrStr.charCodeAt(i);
    if ((word > 47 && word < 58) || (word > 64 && word < 91) || (word > 96 && word < 123)) {
      str.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
}

extractPassword(['a', '-', '~', '1', 'a', '/']);

console.log(str.join(''));
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about Reg.Ex, i didn`t learn about it yet can, but im sure in futute i will be using. They ask for a different way of solution without using Reg.Ex, and using extractPassword as a "function"

Comment: @LeeCassamo What is the issue with `RegEx` ? You don't have to install anything separately for regex and it's easy to use with minimal code.

Comment: my Friend, your answers are correct but to this task when i run it, they say Reg.Ex is cool but not the way they want to. The answer should be more basic and without Reg.Ex... Your answer is correct.

Comment: @LeeCassamo I updated my answer as per your requirement. Please have a look. Hope it will help.

Comment: My Friend to your code i add: extractPassword (['~','A','7','/','C']), and they said: your function is not returning the correct value.

Comment: @LeeCassamo It's returning expected value `"A7C"`. I am not sure what exactly you want. Please make it clear yourself first. I am giving up now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246963/discussion-between-lee-cassamo-and-rohit-jindal).